Unable to submitting the form using jquery post request like a form submit
Using Form Submit redirecting page from one page to another page and the page is redirecting successfully but the parameter value getting length 0(if array) or null(if string) based on the data passed on param.
To achieve this concept I have used the below logic.
Redirecting to page-2 from page-1:-

function redirectopage() {
    post_to_url('http://xxxxxxxxx/option.aspx', {
        data: 'dynamic'
       //option: 't'
    }, 'post', '_blank');
}


Form Submit Logic POST request:-
// Form Submit
function post_to_url(path, params, method, targetOpt) {
    var form = $(document.createElement('form'));
    $(form).attr("action", path);
    $(form).attr("method", method);
    $(form).attr("target", targetOpt);
    
    // Loop through params and append them as hidden inputs
    $.each(params, function(key, value) {
        var input = $("<input>")
            .attr("type", "hidden")
            .attr("name", key)
            .val(value);
        $(form).append(input);
    });

    // Append the form to the body and submit
    $(form).appendTo(document.body).submit();
}


Serializing the data in redirect page(page-2):-
$(document).ready(function() {
    var queryString = $('#form').serializeArray();
      console.log(queryString) //getting null or length 0
    $.each(queryString, function(i, field) {
        alert(field.name + ":" + field.value);
    });
});


Note:- I have created these two pages(using web form{with master page}) in asp.net empty website project and I have read this answer post also but I didn't understand well.
Suggest me where I did the mistake and how to achieve this.
